# Checkbox to remain checked after unchecking the box not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my react project, I have some checkboxes and buttons which I want to check and make sure the button stays on a different when checked and not change again until i click the button to change again.

What I'm doing presently, the buttons stays at watch button but when checked, any button that the checkbox is checked should change to remove and not go back to watch when the checkbox is unchecked. I only want the buttons to go back to remove only when i click on each individual buttons. Here is what I have been able to come up with. and codesandsandbox here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-feather-s0o7r?file=/src/Defaultdata.js:0-645)

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";
import "./Defaultdata";
import Defaultdata from "./Defaultdata";

export default function App() {
  const inputEl = useRef("");
  const inputEl2 = useRef("");

  const [sampledata, setsampledata] = useState({
    type_1: "watch",
    id: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(newdatatoshow);
  }, [sampledata]);

  const [checkboxstate, setcheckboxstate] = useState();
  const [submitting, setsubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [seachstate, setStatevalue] = useState(false);
  const [boxcheck, setboxcheck] = useState(false);

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setStatevalue(!seachstate);
    console.log(inputEl2.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sampledata);
  }, [sampledata]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sampledata);
  }, [sampledata]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input ref={inputEl2} type="text" />{" "}
        <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th>Item 1</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Item 2</th>
          <th>Item 3</th>
          <th>Item 4</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Defaultdata.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <span
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      setcheckboxstate(e.target.checked);
                      setsampledata({
                        ...sampledata,
                        id: [...sampledata.id, item.id]
                      });
                      if (!e.target.checked) {
                        setsampledata({
                          ...sampledata,
                          id: sampledata.id.filter(function (n) {
                            return n !== item.id;
                          })
                        });
                      }
                      // console.log(sampledata.id.includes("NG3088568879"));
                    }}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    <input type="checkbox" ref={inputEl} />{" "}
                  </span>{" "}
                </td>

                <tr>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  {sampledata.id.includes(item.id) &&
                  sampledata.id.includes(item.id) ? (
                    <button>Remove</button>
                  ) : (
                    <button>Select</button>
                  )}
                </tr>
                <td>{item.distance}</td>

                <td>{item.date_listed}</td>
                <td>{item.mode}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

default data

```
const Defaultdata = [
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    id: "7857699961",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
    distance: "22.8 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:36:54",
    watched: "yes",
    mode: "car"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "3 days ago",
    id: "8358962006",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-24",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-22 16:54:12",
    mode: "truck"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    id: "8146462294",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32",
    mode: "bike"
  }
];



export default Defaultdata
```

Comment: unfortunately, i don't understand this part "What I'm doing presently, the buttons stays at watch button but when checked, any button that the checkbox is checked should change to remove and not go back to watch when the checkbox is unchecked. I only want the buttons to go back to remove only when i click on each individual buttons."

Comment: please explain your expectations clearly.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to disable the checkbox once selected? And only uncheck it when you click on "Remove" button?

Comment: I want the clicked button to change to remove button when checked and stays on remove button until i click on the button itself before it changes to watch again. right now all the buttons are on watch but anytime i check on any of the buttons, it changes to another button. remove button in this situation.  @novonimo

Comment: @JayendraSharan Can you please see my comment

Comment: I'm not getting you sorry. Do you mean that need a way to select and remove the check box with the button? like the behavior on selecting and deselection the checkbox?

Comment: as a side note, your codesandbox project will throw an error because you've forgotten to add the `DefaultData`  into it.

Comment: when i click select on any of the checkboxes, the button of that particular one change to remove from watch